# Bootstrap Calendar order of events in week view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar

I have a high interest in creating my own event calendar/scheduler for my site and found [Bootstrap Calendar](http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/index-bs3.html), it has real potential. I looked at [dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/) but its hard to customize the look, it has a lot of nice features though. I have a Fullcalendar now and I like the new [Scheduler](http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/) but   I still want a more custom look and some custom functionally.

My JS/Jquery is limited so it makes it difficult to get a real picture of BS-Cal layout and unfortunately there seems to be little documentation other than comments in the code.

So my issue with BS-Cal is the event ordering/stacking in the week view.

The Question - Can the events be reordered in a per day list like the 2nd photo below.

So far - I see the offset class for the columns and the events but the events seem to be wrapped in a "row" div which forces a single "list" for the whole week rather than per day placement order left to right on the table.

Here is what I believe is happening:

[image]

This is what I'm hoping to accomplish:

[image]